# New tp-link AC600 wireless USB does not work

Tags: wireless, wpa-supplicant

I am struggeling to bring up a tp-link AC600 Archer T2U nano USB wireless adapter. I run a ubuntu eoan with kernel 5.3.0-42-generic

First I installed the latest 8812au driver with dkms. Now I have

```
# dkms status
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.3.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
```

With that module, ubuntu recognizes my new wlan0.

iwconfig says:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
```

But in the Network Manager the new device does not appear. I the logs I just see:

```
NetworkManager[8760]: <warn>  [1585400935.4713] device (wlan0): re-acquiring supplicant interface (#5).
wpa_supplicant[6147]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Operation not permitted
wpa_supplicant[6147]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
(...)
```

New config file for wpa_supplicant.

Same log entries as above. Now I tried to start wpa_supplicant directly in debug mode:

```
# wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -i wlan0 -dd
wpa_supplicant v2.9
random: getrandom() support available
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf' driver 'default' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf'
ctrl_interface='DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel'
Line: 5 - start of a new network block
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=5):
     6d 69 73 63 68                                    misch           
scan_ssid=1 (0x1)
key_mgmt: 0x2
PSK (ASCII passphrase) - hexdump_ascii(len=12): [REMOVED]
PSK (from passphrase) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='misch'
(...)
rfkill: initial event: idx=3 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Operation not permitted
nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
(...)
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Failed to add interface wlan0
```

How to solve the problem that wpa_supplicant does not seem to be allowed the bring up the interface?

Michael